# InnerHTML in multiple fiields and more than one error statements

Tags: javascript, html, input, onblur

I am having trouble trying to get the form to validate using the onblur handler.

What I am trying to do is to get the first and last name field to display an  error message if the field is blank, if it’s less than 5 , more than 18 characters, or it the user enters a number.

I would like to be able to do this using only one function so I do not need to do this for seperate functions.

Eg:

```js
function ValidateName(field) {
  var field = field.value;
  var output = document.getElementById("fnameError");
   if (field == "")
 {
   output = "field can’t be blank.";
   return false;
 }
   else
 {
   output = "";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="Text" id="Fname" onblur="ValidateName(this)">
<span id="fnameError"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see my answer. Please comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer according to the question.

```js
function ValidateName(field) {
  var output = document.getElementById("fnameError");
   if (field.value == "")
 {
   output.innerHTML = "field can’t be blank.";
 }
   else
 {
   output.innerHTML = "";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="Text" id="Fname" onblur="ValidateName(this)">
<span id="fnameError"></span>
</form>
```

Your answer according to the the comment made on my answer.

```js
function ValidateName() {
  var outputF = document.getElementById("fnameError");
  var outputL = document.getElementById("lnameError");
  var outputB = document.getElementById("BothError");
  var field1 =  document.getElementById("Fname");
  var field2 =  document.getElementById("Lname");
  
    if (field1.value == "" && field2.value == "")
 {
   outputF.innerHTML = "";
   outputB.innerHTML = "No field can be left blank.";
   outputL.innerHTML = "";
 }
   else if (field1.value !== "" && field2.value == "") 
{
   outputF.innerHTML = "";
   outputB.innerHTML = "";
   outputL.innerHTML = "field can’t be blank.";
   }
   else if (field1.value == "" && field2.value !== "")
   {
   outputF.innerHTML = "field can’t be blank.";
   outputB.innerHTML = "";
   outputL.innerHTML = "";
   }
else {
   outputF.innerHTML = "";
   outputB.innerHTML = "";
   outputL.innerHTML = "";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="Text" id="Fname" onblur="ValidateName()">
<span id="fnameError"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="Text" id="Lname" onblur="ValidateName()">
<span id="lnameError"></span>
<br><br>
<span id="BothError"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I will have more than one fields, each field should will have a span tag. How do I make this happen e.g: the First name field has a span tag and error is showing next to the first name field and the last name field, it should be showing next to the last name field. Is it possible to make it work using one function?

Comment: Check the second code snippet in my answer. If this works for you, please up-vote and give me the tick mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this also

function validateform(){  
var name=document.myform.name.value;  

if (name==null || name==""){  
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}
else if(name.length < 5){
    alert("name must be atleast 8 characters long");
    return false;
}
else if(name.length <18){
alert("text must be more than 18 characters");
return false;
}

}  

<form name="myform" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateform()" >  
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>   
<input type="submit" value="register">  
</form>
```